# PHP: Next Value in Associative Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two associative arrays `$jar_array` and `$julla_array`.

I looping through them like this

```
foreach ($jar_array as $k => $v) {
    foreach ($v as $ke => $vl) {
        print_r($vl);
        print_r($julla_array[$k][$ke]);
        print_r(next($julla_array[$k][$ke]));//this doesn't work
        exit;
    }
}
```

The problem is : The `next()` function does not return the next value in `$julla_array`. What am I doing wrong here?

I tried adding references like this

```
foreach($jar_array as $k => &$v){

foreach($v as $ke => &$vl){
    print_r($vl);
    print_r($julla_array[$k][$ke]);
    print_r(next($julla_array[$k][$ke]));
    exit;
   }
}
```

This doesn't help either.

The `$jar_array` contents look like this

```
    Array
(
    [2667] => Array
        (
            [2017-10-13] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2147831419
                [jar_id] => 2147831419
                [1] => 2667
                [jar_userid] => 2667
                [2] => 2017-10-13
                [jar_date] => 2017-10-13

             )

        )

   )
```

The `$julla_array` contents look like this

```
    Array
(
    [2667] => Array
         (
             [2017-10-13] => Array
                (
                [0] => 5380097
                [julla_id] => 5380097
                [1] => 2017-10-13 18:00:41
                [julla_date] => 2017-10-13 18:00:41
                [2] => 2667
                [julla_userid] => 2667
                [3] => 112
                [julla_shift] => 112
                [4] => 2
                [julla_action] => 2
                [5] => 2017-10-13
                [n_julla_date] => 2017-10-13
               ) 
         )
    )
```

Comment: Can you please share the content of those var? (`$julla_array`)

Comment: @dWinder added the contents